# Nested tf.map_fn with slow performance

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run the code below in order to get a padding matrix from a given matrix of indices (words_chars_ids shape is (6,200,20)).
The result has the shape (6,200,20,emb_size) where for each entry in the output it holds a tensor of ones or zeroes (with size emb_size).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more elegant way to implement this method (without the nested map_fn)
2. The performance seems to be quite slow - is there a more efficient way to achieve the result ?

```
def get_padding_mask(words_chars_ids, emb_size):

    padding_mask = tf.map_fn(
        lambda x: tf.map_fn(
            lambda y: tf.map_fn(
                lambda z: tf.cond(tf.less(z, 1),
                                  lambda: tf.zeros([emb_size, ], dtype=tf.int32),
                                  lambda: tf.ones([emb_size, ], dtype=tf.int32)
                                  ),
                y),
            x),
        words_chars_ids)
    return padding_mask
```

Comment: _The performance seems to be quite slow - is there a more efficient way to achieve the result?_ As soon as we're talking performance, we need benchmarks, profiling results, and ideally all the necessary code and data to do these things ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing simply as:

```py
def get_padding_mask(words_chars_ids, emb_size):
    mask = tf.dtypes.cast(words_chars_ids >= 1, tf.int32)
    return tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(mask, -1), [1, 1, 1, emb_size])
```